# ArrayList Student Login compilation error

Tags: java, search, arraylist, system, bluej

I'm having a problem with my code. I am trying to create a student log in which when entered correctly will allow the user to access the memberEnter() part and if its wrong the system should exit.

I've been trying to compile the code and it's been giving me an error can anyone help me fix this?

The error I get is:

```
cannot find symbol - variable studentidlogin
```

The line where the error occurs is

```
if(mem.studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member "))
```

In the `main` method of `MainSystem` (also marked in the code itself).

Main System Code:

```
import java.io.*;//imports the io package
import java.util.Scanner;//imports scanner
import java.util.*;//imports the util package

public class MainSystem {

    static String fileName = null;
    static Library lib = new Library();
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Boolean running = true;
    static Member mem = new Member();//static variables that can be initialised at compile time, but can be modified at run time

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {// there has to be an input/output
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//allows the user to type in the script.
        String user, password;
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 0 To login as a Librarian"
                + "\nEnter 1 to Login"
                + "\nEnter 2 to Sign Up");//first display screen in the interface.

            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 0:

                System.out.println("\nEnter Username: ");
                user = br.readLine();

                System.out.println("\nEnter Password: ");
                password = br.readLine();//if '0' is selected this is displayed.

                if (user.matches("enter") && (password.matches("Password")))// if 0 is entered this has to be entered.
                {
                    librairanEnter();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }  

                case 1:
                String studentidlogin;
                System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID: ");
                studentidlogin = br.readLine();//if '1' is pressed this is displayed           
                System.out.println(mem.studentidlogin(studentidlogin));

                /************* ERROR OCCURS HERE **************/
                if(mem.studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member "))
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }else
                {
                    memberEnter();
                    break;
                }

                case 2:
                newMember();//if '2' is selected this is displayed.
                break;

            }
        }

    }

    private static void newMember() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int libraryNumber;
        String StudentID, Username, FullName, Address, email, PhoneNumber;

        System.out.println("\nEnter Library Number: ");
        libraryNumber= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());;//prompts user to enter library number.

        System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID: ");//prompts user to enter student id.
        StudentID = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Full Name: ");//prompts user to enter full name
        FullName = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Username: ");//prompts user to enter username
        Username = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter E-Mail Address: ");//prompts user to enter an email address
        email = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Home Address: ");//prompts user to enter home address
        Address = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Phone Number: ");//prompts user to enter phone number
        PhoneNumber = br.readLine();

        StudentSignUp b = new StudentSignUp(libraryNumber, FullName, StudentID, Username, Address, email, PhoneNumber);
        mem.newMember(b);

        System.out.println("\nThankyou. You can now Login.: ");// prompts user that they can now sign in.
    }

    private static void memberEnter() throws IOException {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 0 for load a library."
                + "\nEnter 1 for save and quit"
                + "\nEnter 2 for list all books in library"
                + "\nEnter 3 for Search For A Book");//options available if member is enters.

            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter the file name to load");
                loadScript(in.next());//loads previously saved script
                break;
                case 1:
                saveAndQuit();//saves and quits from the system
                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println(lib.toString());//lists all the books in the library
                break;
                case 3:
                searchBook();//searches for a book
                break;

            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void librairanEnter() throws IOException {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 0 for load a library."
                + "\nEnter 1 for save and quit"
                + "\nEnter 2 for list all books in library"
                + "\nEnter 3 for add book to library"
                + "\nEnter 4 for Search For A Book"
                + "\nEnter 5 for list of current members"
                + "\nEnter 6 to borrow a book"
                + "\nEnter 7 to return a book");//options available if the librarian logs in.

            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter the file name to load");
                loadScript(in.next());//loads previously saved libraries
                break;
                case 1:
                saveAndQuit();//saves and quits
                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println(lib.toString());//prints current books in library
                break;
                case 3:
                addBook();//adds a book to the system
                break;
                case 4:
                searchBook();//searches for a book in the system
                case 5:
                System.out.println(mem.toString());//list of current members
                break;
                case 6:
                borrowBook();//allows to borrow a book.
                case 7:
                returnBook();//allows to return a book.

            }
        }
        System.exit(0);//exits from the system/
    }

    private static void addBook() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int isbn, numcopies;
        String author, title, genre;// initializes the variables

        System.out.println("\nEnter ISBN: ");
        isbn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());//prompts user to enter isbn

        System.out.println("\nEnter Author: ");//prompts user to enter the auth
        author = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Title: ");//prompts user to enter title
        title = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Genre: ");//prompts user to enter genre
        genre = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Number Of Copies: ");//prompts user to enter number of copies
        numcopies = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        Book b = new Book(isbn, author, title, genre, numcopies);//Creates the new book and adds it to the library
        lib.addBook(b);
    }

    private static void saveAndQuit() {//saves and quits
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter file name: ");//prompts the user to enter the file name.
        fileName = in.next() + ".ser";//saves the file name
        running = false;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(lib);
            fos.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void loadScript(String name) {//loads a previously saved script
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        File file = new File(name + ".ser");
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                lib = (Library) in.readObject();
                fis.close();
                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("\nThe file does not exist!");
        }
    }

    private static void searchBook() throws IOException//allows searching for a book
    {
        String titleSearch;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 0 to search on title."////prompts the user to answer 0
                + "\nEnter 3 to go back");//promts the user to enter 3

            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter the book Title");//promts the user to enter the title of the book
                titleSearch = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(lib.searchTitle( titleSearch));

                break;
                case 3:
                librairanEnter();//takes the user back to the librarian home page.

            }
        }
    }

    private static void borrowBook() throws IOException
    {
        String titleBorrow;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 0 to search on title."//prompts the user to answer 0
                + "\nEnter 3 to go back");//prompt the user to answer 3

            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter the book Title");//promts the user ot enter the book title
                titleBorrow = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(lib.borrowBook( titleBorrow));

                break;
                case 3:
                librairanEnter();//takes the user back to the librarian home page.

            }
        }
    }

    private static void returnBook() throws IOException
    {
        String returnedBook;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 0 to retrun a book."//promts the user to enter 0
                + "\nEnter 3 to go back");//prompts the user to enter 3

            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
                case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter the book Title");//promts the user to enter the book title.
                returnedBook = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(lib.returnBook( returnedBook));

                break;
                case 3:
                librairanEnter();//takes the user back to the librarian home page.

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Member Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Member here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

public class Member
{
   private List<StudentSignUp> memberList;//creates the array list


    public Member()
    {
        memberList = new ArrayList<StudentSignUp>(); //makes the 'memberList' the array list. 
    }
    public void newMember(StudentSignUp student)
    {
        memberList.add(student);//adds a student to the array list.
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String totalmem = "\n ";
        for (int i=0; i<memberList.size(); i++)
        {
            StudentSignUp b = memberList.get(i);
            totalmem = totalmem + b.toString(); //prints out all students
        }

        return totalmem;
    }

        public String studentidlogin(String studentidlogin) {
        if (studentidlogin == null) return "\n Not a member ";
        for(int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++){
            if(studentidlogin.equalsIgnoreCase(memberList.get(i).getStudentID())){
                return memberList.get(i).toString();//allows user to search for a book in the system
            }
        }
        return "\n Not a member "; //reachable only if no book found
    }





}
```

Comment: and what's the error? oO

Comment: cannot find symbol - variable studentidlogin

Comment: Not for the error ,but never use "+" to concat strings. Use StringBuilder.

Comment: When asking for help with errors please always include the full error message/stack trace in your question

Comment: how about you post the whole error message with line numbers and more. would be a lot faster

Comment: cannot find symbol - variable studentidlogin

Comment: on line of code in the main system part  if(mem.studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member "))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
        System.out.println(mem.studentidlogin(studentidlogin));

        if(mem.studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member "))
```

The first usage of `mem.studentidlogin`, in the `println()` call, is correct. Since `studentidlogin` is a **method** of the `Member` class, it should be called as a method - with parentheses and arguments that match its parameters.

The second usage is incorrect. You are treating it as if it was a **field**. I think perhaps you expected this to be the result that was returned from the previous call, but if so, Java doesn't work that way.

Besides, I believe you are trying to compare it to the string `"\n Not a member "`. Comparison of strings should only be done with `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`!

As the code stands, it looks like you are trying to assign a value to a field (that doesn't exist), inside an `if` statement that only expects a boolean value (comparison would be `==` which, as I said, you shouldn't use anyway, but you are using assignment `=`).

You have two options. Either call it again properly:

```
        System.out.println(mem.studentidlogin(studentidlogin));

        if(mem.studentidlogin().equals("\n Not a member "))
```

Or preferably, to avoid doing all the work twice, define a variable:

```
        String loginResult = mem.studentidlogin(studentidlogin);
        System.out.println(loginResult);

        if( loginResult.equals("\n Not a member "))
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {// there has to be an input/output
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//allows the user to type in the script.
    String user, password;
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter 0 To login as a Librarian"
            + "\nEnter 1 to Login"
            + "\nEnter 2 to Sign Up");//first display screen in the interface.

        int answer = in.nextInt();
        switch (answer) {
            case 0:

            System.out.println("\nEnter Username: ");
            user = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("\nEnter Password: ");
            password = br.readLine();//if '0' is selected this is displayed.

            if (user.matches("enter") && (password.matches("Password")))// if 0 is entered this has to be entered.
            {
                librairanEnter();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }  

            case 1:
            String studentidlogin;
            System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID: ");
            studentidlogin = br.readLine();//if '1' is pressed this is displayed           
            System.out.println(mem.studentidlogin(studentidlogin));

            if(mem.studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member "))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }else
            {
                memberEnter();
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            newMember();//if '2' is selected this is displayed.
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

to, you did mem.studentidlogin instead of studentidlogin in the if statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {// there has to be an input/output
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//allows the user to type in the script.
    String user, password;
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter 0 To login as a Librarian"
            + "\nEnter 1 to Login"
            + "\nEnter 2 to Sign Up");//first display screen in the interface.

        int answer = in.nextInt();
        switch (answer) {
            case 0:

            System.out.println("\nEnter Username: ");
            user = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("\nEnter Password: ");
            password = br.readLine();//if '0' is selected this is displayed.

            if (user.matches("enter") && (password.matches("Password")))// if 0 is entered this has to be entered.
            {
                librairanEnter();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }  

            case 1:
            String studentidlogin;
            System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID: ");
            studentidlogin = br.readLine();//if '1' is pressed this is displayed           
            System.out.println(mem.studentidlogin(studentidlogin));

            if(studentidlogin.equals("\n Not a member "))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }else
            {
                memberEnter();
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            newMember();//if '2' is selected this is displayed.
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I get another error when i change that: "incompatible types:java.lang.string cannot be converted to boolean"

Answer (score 1):

your function

```
 public String studentidlogin(String studentidlogin)
```

takes a string argument, but you are calling it like this:

```
mem.studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member ")
```

edit:
just to extend my answers. you have a few more problems to solve. maybe reading up on java basics would help.

e.g.

```
 if(studentidlogin = ("\n Not a member "))
```

YOU want to compare two strings and use the assign operator (=),
but in your case you need the equals method.

```
String str = "anything";
if (str.equals("anything")) {
//do something
}
```

I think you meant using the == operator but that only compares two memory spots.